# Explicitly render google recaptcha enterprise widget in next js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to protect a form on my next-js web page with google recaptcha enterprise.
I want to render the logo manually, as the automatic badge on the side interferes with my layout/design.

I added the following to my form page:

```
const key="my-key"

useEffect(() => {
    (window as any).onloadCallback = () => {
      console.log("onloadCallback");
      (window as any).grecaptcha.enterprise.render(captchaRef.current,{sitekey: key});
      });
    };

    // Load reCAPTCHA script dynamically  
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  
    // Clean up the function on component unmount
    // (...)
}

// Form Submit method
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<OrderFormInput> = async (data) => {
    // GetCaptchaToken
    const token = await (window as any).grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(key, {
      action: "place_order",
    });
    data.recaptchaToken = token;

    // debug
    console.log(token)

    // Call backend
    // (...)
}
```

With this I get an error message in the widget:
[Widget when explicitly rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSUqL.png)

And also `onSubmit()` I get an error
`[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js: <my-key>`

When I use:

```
script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=<my-key>'
```

I get a normal looking badge and a valid token, which my backend can also validate.

Is it possible that the Javascript API (-> render method) is broken?
To me at least the error code, which references api.js not enterprise.js looks like it is based of outdated code.
Before recaptcha enterprise was a thing one used to get the script from `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js`..

Documentation Page about the Javascript API to render explicitly lives at:
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/api-ref-checkbox-keys

I created multiple site keys via gcloud console and tried all sorts variants for the script URL.

I also wrapped the render call like this:

```
(window as any).grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(() => {
    try{
        (window as any).grecaptcha.enterprise.render(captchaRef.current,{sitekey: key});
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar situation before, and I hope my response proves helpful. Everything seems to function as expected, except when the checkbox-keys are selected to be on. In such cases, the .grecaptcha.enterprise.execute method triggers an 'Unhandled Promise Rejection' error with the message: 'Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js.' I believe this issue lies on the library side and can be considered a bug.

To address this, a viable workaround involves utilizing the callback setup within the render method. This approach grants the ability to modify the state and provide a valid token. To illustrate, I've provided an example in pure JavaScript, because is not related to Next.js.

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=explicit&hl=sr"></script>

<input type="email" id="inp-email" />
<div id="ele-captcha"></div>
<button id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
    let captchaToken = "";

    grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.render('ele-captcha', {
            sitekey: '---REAL-SITE-KEY---',
            action: "password_reset",
            callback: (token) => {
                // TODO set state
                captchaToken = token
            },
        });
    })

    document.getElementById("btn-submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = document.getElementById("inp-email");
        const payload = {
            token: captchaToken,
            email,
        }
        fetch("/save-form-url", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(r => r.json()).then(j => console.log(j))
    })
</script>
```