# token returned null when using grecaptcha entreprise

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, next.js, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to integrate google recaptcha entreprise in a next.js app, when I use a non test key, the returned token is always null, however it's returned fine when I use a test key.
What is the problem please.

Here is the github link for the repo:
https://github.com/Seif-apprentus/Next-JS-Landing-Page-Starter-Template/blob/master/src/pages/login/index.tsx

Comment: What version are you using ? non test key(secret key) are only supported in  reCAPTCHA v3 and v2, you need to register to get new API key pair, You can follow this [document](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro)

Comment: Entreprise version and I already added non test key, I don't want to use v3 or v2, I want to use entreprise version!

Comment: The GitHub repository link seems to be broken. You might find a comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/77847245/618424 helpful.